# Can I make an anchor tag overlay another anchor tag?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3's carousel and the right side carousel control is overlaying some paragraphs.  Normally this isn't an issue.  However a few slides have links in them and I would like for the user to still be able to click them.

Is it possible to set the z-index of the anchor tags (and only the anchor tags) in the paragraphs so that they are "higher" in the page than the carousel control?

Bootply with example code: http://www.bootply.com/6rOo9TcCNF

Thanks!

Comment: It may be possible, but z-index is a tricky pain...typically whatever is latest in the DOM will be on top...

Comment: Ah gotcha.  Yea the carousel controls come later in the HTML so they are on top.

Comment: yeah, if you change the DOM order it will put the last items above other stuff, if that is feasible for you it may be the easiest. z-index could work, but is usually a super PITA...if you do end up using z-index keep in mind that you need it on each element you want to control the stacking of and that z-indexes have to positive integers.

Comment: @DrCord Thanks.  I tried moving the HTML around but then the buttons were hidden behind the content.  When using z-index to bring them back to the front I was back in the same issue as before I moved it around, haha.  Unfortunately I don't think what I am attempting is possible unless I want to really hack apart Bootstrap's carousel.  Thank you for helping.

Comment: glad to help, sry you couldn't get the effect you wanted.

Comment: Please provide some sample code that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Do you have your carousel paragraph in a container so that they don't overflow into your carousel controls?  If so are you sure you're not talking about overflow into your indicators as opposed to your controls?

Comment: @Shaggy Added Bootply to the question.  I put in lorem ipsum and made the link a whole sentence so that you could see the link going behind the carousel control.  The actual links aren't whole sentences though, which is why they get "hidden" behind the controls.

Comment: @JakeTaylor Added example code.  The paragraphs are flowing behind the anchor tags with classes carousel-control left/right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would be best to just reduce the width of `carousel-control` to something like `35px` and give your slides a little extra padding so that the content is accessible to clicking.

Or

Another alternative would be to give your slide links a high `z-index` and try it out that way so that they overlap the `carousel-control` but that could itself poses some problems.

Comment: This resolves the issue of links falling completely behind the carousel controls.  Thanks.

Comment: Except with the code you had you'd also have to remove your chevron percentage placement as I showed below.  Without doing this your prev. and next icons will flow outside and only be half visible.

Comment: I think that's fairly obvious. no worries KJW glad your sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the position of the carousel control icons, just change the width of your carousel-control to the width of the icons and it should fix your issue.  So first remove:

```
.carousel-control .icon-next, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
    right:15%;
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left {
    left:15%;
```

Then add;
}  `.carousel-control {width:30px!important;}`  Here's the new bootply http://www.bootply.com/EMilPfoDoK